# How to apply mod_rewrite rules to all sub directories?

Tags: mod-rewrite

Recently I added a domain to one of my websites:
Original domain: ss.rsportugal.org
New domain: supremeskillers.net

I used this .htaccess file to force redirects
~/public_html/ss/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^supremeskillers\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://supremeskillers.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But redirects aren't working for the forum subdirectory and I wonder if the problem is the 'pretty urls' .htaccess:
~/public_html/ss/forum/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /forum

# Rules for: actions
RewriteRule ^(activate|admin|announce|attachapprove|buddy|calendar|clock|collapse)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(coppa|credits|deletemsg|display|dlattach|editpoll|editpoll2|emailuser)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(findmember|groups|help|helpadmin|im|jseditor|jsmodify|jsoption)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(lock|lockvoting|login|login2|logout|markasread|mergetopics|mlist)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(moderate|modifycat|modifykarma|movetopic|movetopic2|notify|notifyboard|openidreturn)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(pm|post|post2|printpage|profile|quotefast|quickmod|quickmod2)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(recent|register|register2|reminder|removepoll|removetopic2|reporttm|requestmembers)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(restoretopic|search|search2|sendtopic|smstats|suggest|spellcheck|splittopics)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(stats|sticky|theme|trackip|about:mozilla|about:unknown|unread|unreadreplies)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(verificationcode|viewprofile|vote|viewquery|viewsmfile|who|\.xml|xmlhttp)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: boards
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: topics
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*|msg[0-9]*|new)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.$3 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is that ss.rsportugal.org/ is correctly redirected and ss.rsportugal.org/forum isn't redirected.
Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't sort out exactly what's going wrong here from the configurations (no easy way of telling what rules *are* getting applied) but maybe I can offer some troubleshooting advice.

- Simplify. Fewer moving parts make for easier debugging. In particular, have a look at [When Not to Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite). I'd suggest for example replacing your domain-forwarding rewrite like so:

  Redirect / http://supremeskillers.net/
- Try setting it up in the main `.htaccess` without the `RewriteBase` directive. That one always confuses things.
- You may be able to simplify your "actions" block using the `Redirect` directive as well.
- Try testing one rewrite at a time.

Comment: I was able to fix it by moving the contents of forum/.htaccess to .htaccess, removing the RewriteBase as you told and fixing the rules without the need for Base. Can I use 'Redirect' with .htaccess? (I don't have access to Apache configuration files)

Comment: It depends on your web host. Different hosts allow different directives in `.htaccess` files, from all to none. If you ask them, they should be able to tell you (or you could just try it, and ask them if it doesn't work.)